# I am trying to push my app using cf push command but I keep on getting this error below

Tags: python

```
 print temp1[int(i0*len(temp1)),:int(i1*len(temp1))]
```

and here is the error

```
2017-02-06T11:41:57.72+0200 [APP/0]      ERR TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma before the colon. The working code (assuming variables are correctly set) should be:

```
print temp1[int(i0*len(temp1)):int(i1*len(temp1))]
```